# How to Split '_' from File Name and Make it Folder Name EX:ABCD_1234.csv I want to Make Folder Name ABCD

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image]

I want to split _ and make it folder I used set variable

[image]

But other filenames too added in different folder

[image]

I was used adf set variable but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have repro'd the same in my environment. Below are the steps.

- Two files are taken in BLOB storage with the
  **File names** ,
  1. kna1_31102022.xlsx
  2. knvv_21092022.xlsx
  [image]
- These file names are added in config table and the table is referred in lookup activity.
  [image]
- For each activity is added sequentially next to lookup.[image]
- Copy activity is added inside For-each.
  [image]
- In source dataset of Copy activity, FilePath is given as
  `container1//@string(item().name)`
  [image]
- In sink dataset's file path is given as below.
  container name: container1
  folder name:  `@split(string(item().name),'_')[0]`
  filename: `@split(string(item().name),'_')[1]`

[image]

**EDITED- To give full filename**

- `@string(item().name)`  in the filename of sink dataset will give the full file name.
  [image]
  **Output:**
  After this pipeline is run, folder and file are created in the required format.
  [image]

**Output After Edit**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you For your Answer @Aswin But I want Full Filename in Container1 ,I think you have given Only Date Part to Container Ex:Inside Kna1 folder I need to pass kna1_31102022.xlsx.

Comment: In sink dataset, instead of giving `@split(string(item().name),'_')[1]` as filename, Give `@string(item().name)`.

Comment: It has Started working @Aswin Thank you so much